Induced representations of kind $ind^G_G(\sigma)$
Let us consider a Hausdorff locally compact topological group G. I would like to understand the form of $ind^G_G(\sigma)$, where $\sigma \in Hom(G,U(\mathbb H))$ and $\mathbb H$ is a  Hilbert space. In this case, the Hilbert space on which $ind^G_G(\sigma)$ acts should be equivalence to $L^2(G/G)\otimes \mathbb H \simeq \mathbb H$. Moreover, because $ind^G_G(\sigma)$ acts as left shifting, i.e., $ind^G_G(\sigma)[f](x) = f(g^{-1} x)$, in this case $ind^G_G(\sigma)$ should be the trivial representation. Am I correct?
